Find Text and copy another cells
I have a Google Sheet where all the users who play the wheel of fortune are copied.
In column E, for example, these values ​​are copied from the database:
a:1:{i:0;s:12:"Half Price";}
I would like the script to extract only the prize won "Half Price" in column H, on the same line.
If no win is made (as in E7) I can write NO WIN
I attach an image for clarity


Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Try these Approaches
1. Using Apps Script
For this part loop through each row to extract the prize text or "NO WIN"
const results = data.map(row => {
        const prizeData = row[0];
        if (prizeData === 'a:0:{}') {
          return ['NO WIN'];
        }

and for this one Regex to extract the prize text from the pattern a:1:{i:0;s:12:"Metà Prezzo";}
    const match = prizeData.match(/s:\d+:\"([^\"]+)\"/);
    const prize = match ? match[1] : null;

Script used
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  const prizeColumn = sheet.getRange(2, 8, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  const data = dataRange.getValues();

  const results = data.map(row => {
    const prizeData = row[0];
    if (prizeData === 'a:0:{}') {
      return ['NO WIN'];
    }

    const match = prizeData.match(/s:\d+:\"([^\"]+)\"/);
    const prize = match ? match[1] : null;

    if (prize === "Metà Prezzo" || prize === "NO WIN") {
      return [prize];
    } else {
      return [''];
    }
  });

  prizeColumn.setValues(results);
}

Sample Output

2. Using Google sheet Formula
The BYROW function in combination with LAMBDA, IF, and FIND to process each value in a range of cells from E2 to E8, check for specific conditions, and return corresponding values based on those conditions.
=BYROW(E2:E8, LAMBDA(r, IF(r = "a:0:{}", "No Win", IFERROR(IF(FIND("Metà Prezzo",r)>0,r,""),""))))


References

Syntax for Regular Expressions
BYROW
FIND


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
